# grid search with weighted AUC

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, auc

So I am using the sample weights function and I don't want to measure performance using the default sklearn scoring function.

It looks like it says [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring) that I can pass `GridSearchCV` the string 'roc_auc' and it should calculate auc for me but will the auc it calculates be a weighted auc or just a vanilla auc?

Comment: It appears that `GridSearchCV` does not support `sample_weight`. You could tune the model without weights, use `cross_val_predict`, and then score it weighted yourself. I'm guessing that's not what you are looking for though.

Comment: `GridSearchCV` accepts sample weights via the `fit_params` option (since sample weights needs to be passed to the `fit` method).  I am also using `RandomizedSearchCV` which would require a fair amount of complexity to reproduce using `cross_val_predict` so I am hoping that the `scorer` automatically handles weights but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Does that really work though? The weights would need to be divided into the folds as well. They cannot be naively passed through to the fit function.

Comment: Yes it works.  Since the input cv is just an index it just applies that index to the sample weights the same way that it does with the X and y matrices.  You don't pass it to the fit function on grid search but the `fit_params` option.  I am sure this part works but I'm not sure that any scorer would be passed a similar argument.

Comment: I can't believe that works, but it does. It does not pass the `sample_weight` to the scorer though :-(

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering the same thing, when it `fit` is called, `GridSearchCV` filters the values of `fit_params` the same way it filters `X`, and `y`.  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c9572494a82b364529374aafca15660a7366e2c4/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L1311

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the nerd snipe.

I crafted a binary classification dataset to test this problem.

```
x y weight 
0 0   1
1 1   1
<repeated 25 times>
0 1   0
1 0   0
<repeated 25 times>
```

Using python:

```
X = np.array([[0], [1]] * 25 +  [[0], [1]] * 25)
y = np.array([ 0 ,  1 ] * 25 +  [ 1 ,  0 ] * 25)
w = np.array([ 1 ,  1 ] * 25 +  [ 0 ,  0 ] * 25)
```

In this dataset, we can see that if sample weights are present, the model will produce a very good fit and have a very low log loss. If the weights are not present, the loss will be extremely high.

Then we can build use `GridSearchCV` to see if the weights are used.

```
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg', C=100)
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, {},
                  fit_params={"sample_weight": w}, 
                  scoring="log_loss", cv=KFold(y.shape[0],10, shuffle=True))
gs.fit(X,y)
gs.grid_scores_

[mean: -2.68562, std: 0.68038, params: {}]
```

We can see the loss is fairly high, which would indicate the weights are not used.

I wrote a patch to scikit-learn to fix this. Please consider it experimental. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/compare/master...dmaust:master

After applying the patch, we can enable `score_sample_weight`, repeat the previous test, and can see the log loss we would expect from the weights being taken into account.

```
gs.score_sample_weight=True
gs.fit(X,y)
gs.grid_scores_

[mean: -0.00486, std: 0.00016, params: {}]
```

Comment: Not yet. Planning to shortly

Comment: Yes. You could probably replace two methods in  the cross validation module for the time being.